# Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, database

How do I make the MySQL give the user access and not deny?
how do i add the command too add permissions?

This is the full error

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 
Database error: Link-ID == false, connect failed
MySQL Error: 0 ()
Session halted.
```

Comment: Connecting to mysql is well documented. Google the appropriate library, you use. I am sure, you can find the error yourself

Comment: Also, you better use newer libraries like `mysqli_*`

Comment: Give the connect query you are using...

Comment: MySQL is down, unreachable or the details in config.php are not up to date.

Comment: Your question is way too vague. Please add info on what you are trying to do.

Comment: i'm basically trying to get my website to work but it wont work if it can't connect to the database so basically i guess i need someone to tell me how to add the grant all permissions command to the sql database so i can see if that'll fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you allowed access to the MySQL server for the login/server combination you provide?

```
grant all permissions on *.* 'bf_cards_user'@'My Server IP'
    identified by 'bbeqvfyAwPWECvWs';
flush privileges;
```

or

Either your username, password or database name is wrong.

The error message is deliberately vague in order that unauthorised system-crackers are not helped to find out what they need to change; although I guess you know your username and password.

Refer here http://www.simfatic.com/forms/troubleshoot/mysql-connect-failed.html

Comment: yes username password and database name is correct in the .config file however how do i add that command that you gave in order too allow access? and it's an linux VPS server with cpanel/whm installed